# Cropping a TIFF to a ShapeFile

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, geolocation, geo

Hope you are well I was wondering how to take a tiff file and remove the area that is not of interest in this case I am taking tiff files with crs epsg:4326 and trying to cut it in to the shape of Colombia.

```
path = (*****)
    archivos = glob.glob(path + "/*.tif")
    if len(archivos) > 0:
        for archivo in archivos:
            imagen = rxr.open_rasterio(archivo,masked=True).squeeze()
            imagen.crs
            cliped_imagen=imagen.rio.clip(shape_colombia.geometry.apply(mapping),shape_colombia.crs)
```

Thanks

Comment: Consider giving example of input.  Also show expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this script should solve the problem:

Input:

- tifffs
- shapefile

Output:

- clipped_tiffs

Project structure:

```
your_project
    ├── tiffy
    │   ├── your_tiff_files
    |   ...
    |
    ├── your_python_script
    |
    └── zipdata
        ├── your_shp_data.CPG
        ├── your_shp_data.dbf
        ├── your_shp_data.prj
        ├── your_shp_data.sbn
        ├── your_shp_data.sbx
        ├── your_shpapefile.shp
         ...
```

The structure of the project is important because when loading tiffs, we change the working directory to save the clipped tiffs in the tiff's directory and not litter.

Script:

```
import os
import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import rioxarray as rxr
import geopandas as gpd


crop_extent = gpd.read_file("zipdata/your_shpapefile.shp")
crop_extent = crop_extent.to_crs(epsg=3857)
os.chdir(os.getcwd() + "/tiffy")
extension = 'tiff'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
tiffs = [rxr.open_rasterio(f) for f in all_filenames]


for tiff_name in all_filenames:
    raster = rxr.open_rasterio(tiff_name)
    # IMPORTANTLY check if have the same crs
    assert crop_extent.crs == raster.rio.crs, "diffrent crs"
    tiff_clipped = raster.rio.clip(crop_extent.geometry.apply(mapping),
                                      # This is needed if your GDF is in a diff CRS than the raster data
                                      crop_extent.crs)
    tiff_clipped.rio.to_raster(tiff_name + 'cropped.tif')
    clipped_chm = rxr.open_rasterio(tiff_name +'cropped.tif')
    f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 5))
    clipped_chm.plot.imshow()
    ax.set(title="Chorzow")
    ax.set_axis_off()
    plt.show()
```

You can find the cropped files in the tiffs directory.

Nice day ;)